# Declaring and Initialising variables

Tags: c#, .net, variables, visual-studio-2012, variable-declaration

I wanted to know why we cant do this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string b;
    b = "something";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

However I am able to do this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string b = "something";
```

or

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string b;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b = "something";
    }
```

I have been looking for an answer, why cant we use the first way. However I havent been able to find an answer.

Comment: `b` is a field associated with the class `Form1` and not a variable in the normal sense.  Variables can only be reassigned in methods, properties, or constructors.  I'm sure there's a much more technical explanation involving the C# language spec.

Comment: When you declare and initialise in one step, the value is assigned as a part of the declaration.  As @ryanyuyu said, `b= "something";` is a full statement which is outside of the normal construct where statements are executed.

Comment: 'b = "something";' is a statement, and statements cannot exist outside of a method, property, or event declaration. You can't have it where you've got it, and more than you could have an `if` statement there.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, a class can contain declaration of following members...

`Constructors
Destructors
Constants
Fields
Methods
Properties
Indexers
Operators
Events
Delegates
Classes
Interfaces
Structs`

assigning value to a variable is treated as a `statement` . Again statements are  also categorized in various types. 
Now, your question arises a confusion between `Declaration statements` and `Expression statements`.

**Declaration Statements :** Declaration statements are used to introduce `fields` where assignment is required for constant fields and for variable it is optional. Technically, `Declaration statements` uses `Expression statements` as a part of it.

**Expression statements** : On the other hand an expression statement's responsibility is to assign value(s) to variables. But creating a variable is not it's responsibility.

So, In order to declare the Fields and constants of a class `Declaration Statements` take part and technically takes `Expression Statements` as part of it. But standalone `Expression Statements` as well as other statements can only be a part of a method, property or event declaration.

you can have more information about class from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx)
and about statements from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173143.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

> I have been looking for an answer, why cant we use the first way.

Well, basically because the C# team decided it's not a good idea to do it like that, or because they never had this idea in the first place.

**But let's go with it for a second:**

You can of course make it a feature request. At that point, they will balance the pro's and the cons. Let's do that, and consider the following piece of code:

```
public class Foo
{
    int x = 12;
    int y;
    y = 12 + MyMethod();

    public Foo()
    {
        y = MyMethod();
    }

    public int MyMethod() 
    { 
       //***
       return x + 1;
    }
}
```

Now, the constructor `Foo` will be called when Foo is initialized. So, what value will `y` have after the initialization? And how many times will we call MyMethod? What will happen if we add a second constructor?

I'd say it's pretty confusing, and all this confusion isn't really necessary because there are good constructs ("constructor" and field assignment shorthands) that already allow you to do the necessary things with about the same amount of code.

So there are cons, and no pro's.

To conclude, I wouldn't want these kinds of constructs in my code, which is why I doubt that this will ever be supported.

Answer (score 0):

This statement:

```
string b;
```

is an initialization statement.  Only initialization and declarations / definitions are allowed in a class body.

This statement:

```
b = "something";
```

is an assignment statement, a type of expression.  It actually "returns" something, b.

This statement:

```
string b = "something";
```

This is also an initialization statement.  The reason you can write this one, but not the assignment statement, is because the formal language of c# doesn't let you. I haven't seen the formal language definition, but I imagine it looks something like this

```
InitializationStatement => TypeExpression Symbol  {AssignmentExpressionStatement | ';'}
AssignmentExpressionStatement => '=' EvaluatableExpression ';'
```

The curly braces mean what's inside is optional, and the pipe means or.
This is what makes the language a language the compiler can understand.  The more flexible these rules, the more difficult to make a compiler for it, the more difficult to make development software for it, the more confusing the code.

---

TLDR: You can't put them in for the same reason you can't put 2+2 in a class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

In C# language executable expressions should reside in a method. Classes itself are not executable. They provide the blueprint for an object on how to behave. Classes can only have, methods and properties. In C# properties, events and delegates are also allowed in a class. But internally properties, events and delegates are also methods and variables.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
string b;
b = "something";
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
}
```

in here, string b; is a variable declaration. b="something" is an executable expression. So you cannot have b="something" inside the class directly.
But string b = "something"; is a special syntax which called as initialization. That is defined in C# language. Otherwise you should move b="something" to some method including constructor. Internally initialization code runs when creating a new object, before the constructor is called and we can think it as a part of the constructor.